# Multiple Plugins in single DLL MEF

Tags: plugins, dll, mef

Does MEF allow to host multiple Plugins in single DLL, so that i don't have to create a new class library for every new Plugin ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can have as many types in an assembly as you like, but whether or not those plugins would conflict is down to how you namespace and name them, and how they are exported.

Comment: +1, also note that namespace/How they are exported is an issue to keep in mind whether they are in the same assembly or not.